# How does heartbeat message looks like?

Tags: stomp

In the [STOMP docs, v1.2](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html), I cannot find how a heartbeat message should look like. When logging the incoming traffic I can see lots of line feeds **\n**.

Is the heartbeat message the line feed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regarding the heart-beats themselves, any new data received over the network connection is an indication that the remote end is alive. In a given direction, if heart-beats are expected every  milliseconds:

From the spec the heart-beat is rather vague but in most implementations the heart-beat is the linefeed or '\n' character because that value will not be mistaken for a new incoming frame.